# Why wait method doesn't work on Thread object?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, wait

```
Thread t2 = new Thread();
Thread t3 = new Thread();

t1.start();
t2.start();
synchronized (t2) {
    t2.wait(20000);
}
t3.start();
```

The above program runs without t2 waiting for 20sec. I observed that when thread object is started then it wont wait. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you determine that `t2` does not wait? What does `t2` actually do?

Comment: `wait` has nothing to do with telling `t2` to wait. Do some [research](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-and-sleep) please.

Comment: But what actually happens here i dont understand. Thread instance with wait method does not make the current executing thread wait.

Comment: @KomalPatil `t2` doesn't do anything. It starts and instantly terminates as there is no code for it to run. So the calling thread of `t2.wait` nearly doesn't wait at all. The only thing it waits for is for `t2` to terminate, which notifies the waiter.

Comment: Trying to tell some other thread to wait this way is a bad idea from the beginning. In the long run, designing your threads to act as independent units that communicate as peers is an approach more likely to end up with a good and maintainable solution. Trying to micro-manage threads is about as effective as micro-managing software developers.

Comment: Do not call `wait` or `notify` on a `Thread`, because those methods are used internally to signal thread completion. In your case most likely a `notify` happened when `t2` finished its own `run` method. Use a dedicated monitor object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

First, let's be clear. This function call, `t2.wait(20000)` does not do anything to the `t2` thread. In fact, it doesn't really *do* anything at all. All it does is *not return* until either one of two things happens;

- Some other thread calls `t2.notify()`, or
- 20 seconds elapse.

If the call took less than 20 seconds to return, then that's probably because the `t2` thread itself called `t2.notify()` just before it died. In most implementations of the Java standard library, the `join()` method is implemented by using `wait()` and `notify()` calls on the thread object.

(Note: most authors will advise you *not* to ever call `wait()` or `notify()` on a Thread instance precisely because of the potential for interference between your code and the library code when both call the same methods on the same instance.)

> The above program runs without t2 waiting for 20sec.

As somebody else already has pointed out here, You have not provided any `run()` method for your `t2` thread, so it's unclear why you would expect the `t2` thread to "wait" or, to do anything else at all. The only thing a thread ever does is execute the code that you provide for it in a `run()` method.

The default `Thread.run()` method would call the `run()` method of a *delegate* object that you supply when you construct the threads, but your code supplies no delegate. In that case, the default run() method does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep` to pause the thread regardless of having work to finish.
`wait` doesn't pause the thread, it just waits the thread to finish (and this thread already finished).

Answer (score 0):

```
class SleepThread extends Thread  {    
  //run method for thread
    public void run()    {    
        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)   {    
            try  {  
              //call sleep method of thread
              Thread.sleep(20000);  
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
              System.out.println(e);
            }    

          //print current thread instance with loop variable
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "   : " + i);    
        }    
    }    
}

class Main{
   public static void main(String args[]){  
     //create two thread instances
        SleepThread thread_1 = new SleepThread();    
        SleepThread thread_2 = new SleepThread();    
    //start threads one by one
        thread_1.start();    
        thread_2.start();    
    }    
}
```

[Thread sleep method in java](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/thread-sleep-method-in-java/)